# Can I group the results of jQuery's $.when method?

Tags: jquery, promise

I have the following code:

```
$('#remove-commercial-products-modal').find('form').submit(function() {                              
    var promises = [];
    var $modal = $(this).closest('.modal');                                                          

    $(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {                                         
        promises.push(                                                                               
            $.ajax({
                url: '/commercial/products/unclaim/' + $(this).val() + '/',                          
                dataType: 'json',                                                                    
                timeout: 10000,                                                                      
                cache: false                                                                         
            }));                                                                                     
    });                                                                                              

    $.when.apply($, promises).done(function(result) {                                                
        $modal.modal('hide');                                                                        
    });                                                                                              

    return false;                                                                                    
});
```

So, when my form is submitted, I collect the values of the checked checkboxes, and I created an array of promises, each of which is an $.ajax call.

My calls are executed, and the code in my `.done` function is executed.

However, I think that `.done` is expecting a *number* of arguments, one for each promise. But I don't know how many I have in advance, and I was hoping for an array of results (each one being the response of the $.ajax call.)

Does anybody know if I can have my responses grouped?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
    var l = arguments.length,
        i,
        jqxhr;

    for( i = 0; i < l; ++i ) {
        jqxhr = arguments[i][2]; //The i:th jQXHR passed  
    }                                                              
});
```

See [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/#example-0)

Comment: Thanks. The only exception is that when there was only one promise in the array, `result` contains the response of the $.ajax call directly, instead of the promise object.

Comment: @SalvatoreIovene That's terrible from jQuery... you can check for `arguments.length === 1` as a workaround though?

Comment: @Esalija Almost... in truth, if there was only one promise, then `arguments` contains that promise. Otherwise it contains the array of promises. So I need to check if I'm getting an array or not.

Comment: @SalvatoreIovene ah I see. How about `arguments.length !== promises.length`? Since the `arguments.length` is `3` with 1 promise, but same as the amount of promises if there are more.

Comment: @Esalija that breaks if there are 3 promises. Because then you don't know if you have one or three arguments.

Comment: @SalvatoreIovene If there are more than 1 promise, then `arguments.length === promises.length`, am I not right? Works here http://jsfiddle.net/fFwFW/2/ Gives only `true` for 1 promise, and false for all other cases.

Comment: Yes but a single promise also has a length property - always 3.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I am not checking length of a promise but the length of `arguments` and the length of `promises` (The original array)

Comment: @Esalija If there is one promise, then `arguments.length` will be 3, because the `arguments[0] === my ajax response`, `arguments[1] === "success"` and `arguments[2] === the promise`.

If there are 3 promises instead, `argumetns.length === 3` again, of course.

So I can't tell which is which.

Comment: @SalvatoreIovene if there is one promise, then `promises.length === 1` and `arguments.length === 3`. In all other cases, `promises.length === arguments.length`. So if `promises.length !== arguments.length` returns true, there was only 1 promise. If it returns false, there was more than one promise. See http://jsfiddle.net/fFwFW/4/

Comment: I wonder if this is a browser-dependent bug. Similar has been reported in (older versions of) Firefox.

Comment: Alright, cool, thanks @Esalija and @Beetroot-Beetroot. I can just check for `promises.length`. It works now :-)

Comment: I expect you could alternatively push a dummy (resolved) promise into `promises` as element [0], then start at element [1] in @Esalija 's for loop.